# Почему программа не выводит ожидаемого результата?

Tags: perl

Имеется такой скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

my @array;

foreach (
  qw( a b c d e )
) {
  push @filtered, $_
 if ord( $_ ) % 2;
}
print for "@array\n";
```

Он должен печатать:

> a c e

**Но не печатает**

---

Однако, другой скрипт работает как надо:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = grep {
  ord( $_ ) % 2
} qw( a b c d e );

print for "@array\n";
```

И печатает:

> a c e

---

Почему в первом примере не печатает `a c e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете массив `array`, заполняете `filtered` и выводите `array`, поэтому ничего нет на экране.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array;

foreach (
  qw( a b c d e )
) {
push @filtered, $_ if ord( $_ ) % 2;
}
print for "@filtered\n";
```

Результат:

```
perl a.pl
a c e
```

Comment: хм, спасибо большое!

Comment: т.е. получается 8-я строка была разбита, поэтому и не работало?

Comment: @misdeed Еще раз - оно не работало, потому что вы заполняли массив `filtered`, а выводили `array`. Посмотрите, что я использую в print, а что у вас в коде.

Comment: всё, понял, спасибо! голова уже не работает ваще